# Display For Loop Iterations

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

This is a basic for loop question. If I have a simple for loop such as:

```
function printMe()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = i;
    }
};

printMe();
```

When I call the function, it only prints the last number in the loop 5.  But, how can I make it print ever iteration of the loop so the final list is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: You'd need to write some code that would read the existing value and then modify it with both the new value and the comma you want.

Comment: You are always replacing .innerHTML, but you need to append to it: `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += i + ", ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constantly overwriting the value of `innerHTML` because you are using `innerHTML = i`. This means that when the loop has finished running, the value will be the last value of `i`.

You want to use `+=` to append `i` to the existing value, and you might want to add a space after that as well so they aren't glued together.

```
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += i + " ";
```

Which is a shorthand notation for

```
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML + i + " ";
```

Thus: get the old value, add the new value, store it once again in `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Will mark the answer as correct when the timer runs out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assign `i` into `innerHTML` each loop (not append `+=`), so it is an expected behavior to have the only last output

Try the following will be fine

```
function printMe()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += (innerHTML.length <= 0 ? "" : ", ") + i;
    }
};

 printMe();
```

and also if you would like to print the `5` also, you have to change the for loop to `for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)` or `for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`

try it on https://jsfiddle.net/v1jnLw23/